# matrix multiplication with get _row get_column - python

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a class Matrix(object) with get_row and get_column definitions. How can I make a matrix multiplication with them?

```
def get_row(self,r):
    get_row = self._m[r]
    return get_row   


def get_column(self,c):
    get_column=[]
    for row in self._m:
        get_column.append(row[c])
    return get_column
```

m2=Matrix(2,[[1,2],[3,4]])
m3=Matrix(2,[[5,6],[7,8]])

gc= m2.get_column(1) ----> [2,4]
gr=m2.get_row(1) ----> [3,4]

The following code works but I have to do it using get_row and get_column

```html
nollmatris=[[0 for r in range(self._size)] for c in range(self._size)]
  for i in range(len(self._m)):         
     for j in range(len(other._m[0])):  
        for k in range(len(other._m)):  
           nollmatris[i][j] += self._m[i][k] * other._m[k][j]
for svar in nollmatris:
    print(svar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is homework, since if it's not homework the answer is "get numpy."

If that's not possible, your best bet is to use a `zip()` as the iterator in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the formal definition of the matrices product:

```
m1, m2 definition
product = [[0 for j in range(len(m2.get_row(0)))] for i in range(len(m1.get_column(0)))]
for i in range(len(product)) :
    for j in range(len(product[0])) :
        for k in range(len(m1.get_row(0))) :
            product[i][j] += m1[i][k]*m2[k][j]
```

Very basic approach, and not optimized at all, but it works.